# How to login to website through python using request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have gone through all the questions on stackoverflow related to this but I can't solve my problem. When I am implementing the follwing code,it runs successfully without any error but nothing gets printed.

```
import requests


payload = {'username': 'user','password': 'pass'}


with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(' file-transfers.in/login.php?rid=worlddomains', 
          params=payload)
    r = s.get('http://file-transfers.in/member_arean.php')
    print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole chapter about Authentication in the [Python requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).

> **Basic Authentication**
>
> Many web services that require authentication accept HTTP Basic Auth.
>   This is the simplest kind, and Requests supports it straight out of
>   the box.
>
> Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth is very simple:

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

> In fact, HTTP Basic Auth is so common that Requests provides a handy
>   shorthand for using it:

```
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

> Providing the credentials in a tuple like this is exactly the same as
>   the HTTPBasicAuth example above.

Comment: Since you neither gave an exact error message nor the actual website you try to access this is the basic answer you had to expect. Also, which of the 8+ methods did you actually implement, with which results? If *Basic Auth* does not work, maybe the website uses another system?

Comment: This is the login page http://file-transfers.in/login.php?rid=worlddomains

Comment: And this is the URL of protected page that I want to read http://file-transfers.in/member_arean.php

Comment: You should edit that into your original question, together with the error you are getting.

Comment: I have edited. I am not getting any error.Only the problem is that nothing gets printed.

Comment: Try to debug step by step. Have a look at the response `p` of your login attempt. You should get some hints there. I cannot help you more, since I have no credentials for that page (and don't want yours). If I try to `get` the `member_arean.php` (spelling?) without authentication, the response status is 200 but the content is indeed empty.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I have executed same thing with the PHP and it is running fine. I am running this code on Pyhton Pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The website in question is expecting you to send your username/pass as POST data, not as URL params so:

```
payload = {'username': 'user','password': 'pass'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://file-transfers.in/login.php?rid=worlddomains', data=payload)
    r = s.get('http://file-transfers.in/member_arean.php')
    print(r.text)
```

There might be more to it once the login passes, but without an account we cannot check what's going on.